# can't find methods in gree/unity-webview

Tags: unity-game-engine, webview

i'm using gree/unity-webview plugin and i can load a website in an android project. All is ok. but i have some problems with methods. After look on inet about how to set transparent background, or also about how to send messages from website to unity, i saw some info about methods i can't find.
by example: AddJavaScriptInterface
by example: SetBackgroundColor

i saw in some internet site info about methods like these following:

```
webViewObject.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
webViewObject.getsettings().setJavaScriptEnabled = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setAllowFileAccess = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setAllowContentAccess = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setDomStorageEnabled = true;
webViewObject.getsettings().setDatabaseEnabled = true;
```

webViewObject.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); is ok but all the others are not existing.As far as i know, im about the right plugin...

why i can not find these and other methods?
thanks in advance

Comment: nobody can help?